# Javascript Explanation of this keyword with code examples

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain to me why 'this' correctly works in the second example of setTimeout and not in the first example?

Below logs 'undefined'

```js
const object = {
  message: 'Hello, World!',

  logMessage() {
    console.log(this.message); // What is logged?
  }
};

setTimeout(object.logMessage, 1000);
```

Below logs 'Hello World'

```
const object = {
  message: 'Hello, World!',

  logMessage() {
    console.log(this.message); // What is logged?
  }
};

setTimeout(() => {
    object.logMessage()
}, 1000);
```

Also,  is the code below logs 4.

```js
var length = 4;

function callback() {
  console.log(this.length); // What is logged?
}

const object = {
  length: 5,
  method(callback) {
    callback();
  }
};

object.method(callback, 1, 2);
```

This code logs 5

```js
var length = 4;

function callback() {
  console.log(this.length); // What is logged?
}

const object = {
  length: 5,
  method(callback) {
    console.log(this.length);
  }
};

object.method(callback, 1, 2);
```

Could someone explain the difference please?
I would expect same results and dont understand it.

Comment: You have to bind the method to an instance: `setTimeout(object.logmessage.bind(object), 1000)`.

Comment: I understand how it can work but i dont understand WHY. I am trying to understand why this looses context when passed to settimeout as object.logMessage.

Comment: When you use the expression `object.logmessage` without it being a function call, it just returns the function, it doesn't have its `this` binding.